# Why is casting Object(null) not null?

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript

When you cast null to an object using `Object(null)`, the result is an object.

When you cast undefined to an object using `Object(undefined)`, the result is an object.

But saying `null as Object` or `undefined as Object` remains null.

Why is this? I can't find anything in the documentation about this.

The objects that result from these casts can have properties set on and read from them. It's as if the cast created information, or removed whatever special information the `null` and `undefined` values have. But there's no indication in the AS3 documentation that the `null` and `undefined` special types are actually objects.

Comment: Simple answer? Because it's flash, and flash is bad. Writing a type with trailing parenthesis is declaring a new object and you're passing null as a constructor parameter for copy or a reinterpret type cast. It's essentially the same as saying var o = new Object(null);. You're still creating an object.

Comment: You're half right, @AscensionSystems. You are creating an Object, but it's not the same as calling `new Object()`, even though the result is the same. The most important thing to understand is that `Object( something )` is not type casting at all: It is *invoking the top level function* called `Object`, which tries to return the *Object value* of something.  And, as it turns out, the Object value of `null` is an empty Object. http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/package.html#Object()

Comment: You need to understand what null and undefined actually are. Null is when a variable has been declared but does not have any value. If a variable has not been declared then it is undefined and there will be a compiler error. trace(null == undefined); //Outputs true and trace(null === undefined); //Outputs false

Comment: Interesting nfo guys Ill check this out when I get home. Flash is a strange animal indeed.

Comment: weltraumpirat — Why is the Object value of `null` an empty Object? From the page you cited: "Every value in ActionScript 3.0 is an object, which means that calling Object() on a value returns that value." This seems to contradict, not reinforce, every explanation given so far in this discussion.

Comment: @spiralganglion Docs: "Every value in ActionScript 3.0 is an object." I'm sorry, but that's wrong. `null` and `undefined` are not of the `Object` type. `null is Object` evaluates to `false`.

Comment: Manish — I just tested every type I could think of, and you're right. Even values like `false` and `NaN` pass an `is Object` test, but `null` and `undefined` are the only things I could find that do not.

Comment: Also, if you (Manish) write up an answer based on our discussion and the points you've made, I'll accept it as the correct answer.

Answer (score 3):

There is a difference between the two casting techniques. Here is a good read on it: http://upshots.org/actionscript-3/as3-casting-objects

Basically, Object(null) actually converts null into an Object while "as" attempts to see if null can be treated as an Object, which it cannot.

Comment: According to [1] and the documentation on the null and undefined types, null is a valid value for a variable of type Object, while undefined is not. So the reason Object(undefined) works is probably that undefined is implicitly coerced into null. But why does the Object(null) cast succeed at turning a null value into a standard object instance? I would expect it to either give another null value, a null reference, or some sort of conversion error.

[1] http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/learn/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7f9c.html#WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7fda

Comment: I agree with the ending part of your answer. The AS keyword invokes RTTI to see if the object being cast shares an inheritance chain with the desired cast type and performs the cast if possible. I don't agree with the part that the VM converts NULL to an object. The VM simply allocates a new Object and assumes NULL or 0 parameters for constructing the object. Same with undefined.

Answer (score 3):

It's easier to explain with a `String` first.

Let's say we do this:

```
var v:* = null;
var s:String = v;
```

What happens? `s` becomes `null`. `null` is a valid value for references of type `String`.

Now instead:

```
var v:* = null;
var s:String = String(v);
```

What happens now? `s` becomes `"null"`. We're explicitly asking for an object of type `String` here, but `null` is of type `Null`, so it must be converted. `null` converted to `String` is `"null"`.

If you were to convert `123.45` to `String`, you would get `"123.45"`. Fair enough.

Now let's try with `Object`.

```
var v:* = null;
var obj:Object = v;
```

`obj` becomes `null`.

Now:

```
var v:* = null;
var obj:Object = Object(v);
```

Here again we're explicitly asking for `obj` to point to a value of type `Object` - which `null` is not. `null` converted to `Object` is an empty object.

Let's see again:

```
var s:String = null;
```

Here the reference `s` of type `String` is pointing to the value `null` of type `Null`.

Reference `String`, value `Null`.

A `String` reference can take a `Null` value, but a `Number` reference cannot take a `Null` value, so when assigning `null` to a `Number` it must be converted (i.e. to `0`).

```
var n:Number = Number(null); // 0
```

Thinking in terms of references and values really helps.

It also helps to remember that **casting is for references, conversion is for values**. `Object(value)` is a conversion. `(value as Object)` is a cast.

Finally, let's try with a user-defined type.

```
class Person {}
```

Then:

```
var person:Person = null;
```

Here `person` becomes `null`, as you would expect.

But:

```
var person:Person = Person(null);
```

`person` becomes `null` again! We asked for a `Person`, but we got a `Null`. How come?

The value `null` cannot be converted to type `Person`. In such a case, the result is the default value for the desired type. The default value for `Person` is `null`.

You can see this converting to `Number` as well.

```
var n:Number = Number("123.45");
```

`n` becomes `123.45`.

```
var n:Number = Number("The quick brown fox, period.");
```

`n` becomes `NaN`.

As the string `"The quick brown fox, period."` cannot be converted to type `Number`, the result is the default value for `Number`, which is `NaN`. This is in contrast to the previous example where we successfully converted `null` to `Number`, yielding `0`.

I could go on.

When in doubt, use the `as` operator. `value as Type` basically amounts to `value is Type ? value : null`. No complicated rules to remember. Use `Type(value)` only when you want to convert a value of one type to a value of another type.

Comment: A few quotes from your answer: "null converted to Object is an empty object", and: "The value null cannot be converted to type Person. In such a case, the result is the default value for the desired type. The default value for Person is null."

I can't seem to combine the logic behind these two statements into a coherent understanding. I get why casting null to another type (like your Person example) is still null, as opposed to an instance of the type. That makes perfect sense. But why is casting null to Object any different?

Comment: Further, from the documentation: "In ActionScript 3.0, the default value for instances of the Object class is null", from [1], and: "Every value in ActionScript 3.0 is an object, which means that calling Object() on a value returns that value", from [2].

[1]http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/learn/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7f9c.html#WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7fda

[2]http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/package.html#Object()

Comment: @spiralganglion It's not "casting," it's conversion. Consider: `Type(value)`. Steps: (1) Try to convert `value` to `Type`; (2) if that fails, use default value. In `Object(null)` step 1 succeeds! In `Person(null)` it fails. Default value for `Object` is `null`, but as conversion succeeds, default value is not required.

Comment: @spiralganglion `null` cannot be converted to a `Person` value, but it can be assigned to a `Person` reference. On the other hand, `null` can be converted to an `Object` value (result: empty object).

Comment: Why does the conversion of a `null` value to the `Object` type succeed? Why does that success result in the creation of an empty Object? Can you point to anything in the documentation that supports this?

Comment: @spiralganglion See documentation for `undefined`: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/package.html#undefined ("The value returned by Object(undefined) is a new Object instance"). Suppose I gave you `null` and asked for an `Object` in return, what would you do? You wouldn't give me `null` - that's not `Object`, that's `Null`. Makes sense to give me a _minimum_ `Object` - an empty object. i.e. you would make a best attempt at satisfying my request.

Comment: Good work finding a mention of this behaviour in the documentation. But it still doesn't answer the question of "why". If you look at the page you linked to, each of the different function results, like `String(undefined)` and `Number(undefined)` make sense: the value is converted into either a reasonable default value (like `NaN` for Number) or some reasonable representation of the value itself (like `"undefined"` for String). But an empty object is neither a reasonable default for Object (as we've established, the default for Object is `null`), nor a reasonable representation of the value.

Comment: @spiralganglion Basically the language designers decided that an empty object was a reasonable conversion for `null`. I tend to agree, too. `null` can be successfully converted into all other built-in types (`Number`, `String`, `Array`, `Date`, etc.), so why leave `Object` out? An empty object seems like a good return value. Also, why would you do `Object(null)` if you want `null` back? I mean why bother at all, unless you want an `Object` value; there's no need to "cast" anything to `Object`, (almost) everything's an `Object`.

Comment: Here's why: `trace(Object(false).constructor)` versus `trace(false.constructor)`. Works for more than just booleans, and is useful in certain cases where you want to act on an untyped variable based on its value's class. But if you pass in a null value, you don't get null back out — you get an object, which can produce some unexpected behaviour if you aren't used to the whole "`Object(null)` makes an empty object" thing.